# How to login to a website properly with Python Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to log in to my `amboss` account using Selenium webdriver with python, but as I dont have much experience with it I dont understand what goes wrong. My credentials (email and password) are correct as I have used them to log into the website before.

Here is my code so far:

```
# run firefox webdriver from executable path 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path = path_to_driver)


driver.get("https://www.amboss.com/us/account/login")

signinusername = config['amboss']['email']
signinpassword= config['amboss']['password']

username = driver.find_element_by_id("signin_username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys(signinusername)

pwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signin_username']")
pwd.clear()
pwd.send_keys(signinpassword)

loginbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/form/div[4]/input").click()
time.sleep(20)

# execute script to scroll down the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")

#element in log in page
newelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='left']/p[1]/strong")
print(newelement.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

What I try to do here is log in to the platform and then grab an element which I see in the welcome page by xpath. Despite that selenium is unable to find this element and I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='left']/p[1]/strong
```

Does anyone understand why this happens? Is it because log in was not successful or could something else be wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: This locator: `//*[@id='left']/p[1]/strong` is on the welcome page or login page? and you success login or failed ?

Comment: @frianH hey- locator is on welcome page, but I am not if login failed or succeded.. if it would fail would I get an output on the console?

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

The elements you were trying to fetch were in an iframe so you need to switch to that iframe so they be visible. The following works, try it.

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id("signin_username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys(signinusername)

pwd = driver.find_element_by_id('signin_password')
pwd.clear()
pwd.send_keys(signinpassword)

loginbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('amboss-button').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
time.sleep(2)
frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frames[4])
newelement = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')[0].text  # This prints the following 'You now have access to AMBOSS—an all-in-one pl....'
print(newelement)
```

Comment: @alordlord Just created an account to check it. What's the action you want to do after the login?

Comment: just to grab an element from the welcome page or navigate to a different url in the platform :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to login to the system and trying to find something.

First of all your login attempt is not correct. You're entering password in the username field in your code.

Please do login like this:

At first, add this import to your python script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Then do login like this:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id("signin_username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys(signinusername)

pwd = driver.find_element_by_id("signin_password")
pwd.clear()
pwd.send_keys(signinpassword)
pwd.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I'm not logging in by clicking the button. Just hitting an ENTER after logging in.
I guess correcting the login attempt will help you to find your element and print contents inside this.

I've created an account in amboss to answer your question and after logging in the only `iframe` I found was from google tag manager with no contents in it. So I'm not really sure if your account contains some other web views.

Hope correcting the login attempt helps.

Comment: hey- thanks for your answer! How can you check if login is successful?

Comment: If `driver.current_url == 'https://www.amboss.com/us/app/index'` then login is successful.

Answer (score -1):

First you wrong this is line :

```
pwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signin_username']")
```

Please change with :

```
pwd = driver.find_element_by_id('signin_password')
```

Second, use conditional `if` for validation success or failed login :

```
click login here
time.sleep(20)#here recommendation use WebDriverWait
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='left']/p[1]/strong"))
if count > 0:
    print("login success")
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='left']/p[1]/strong").text)
else:
    print("login failed")
```

Make sure this is the correct locator : `//*[@id='left']/p[1]/strong`

Comment: That's not the issue. There are iframes in the webpage he is fetching that's why the elements are not visible.

Comment: I don't have account to make sure the element in welcome page inside `iframe`, so I feel there is nothing wrong with my logic, it is emphasized by this statement in my answer : `Make sure this is the correct locator : //*[@id='left']/p[1]/strong`, so why downvote :( ?